# AutoFill causing error on AspNet Cascading DropDownList

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms, autofill

everybody. I have a page and it has a form inside of a asp:UpdatePanel(UP). The form has Name, Address, Phone, ... fields(asp:TextBox). But the City and State are asp:DropDownList(DDL) controls. The State DDL filters the City DDL. When the State DDL changes, it fires the SelectedIndexChanged event that will make the City DDL show only that state cities. The problem is happening when my browser suggests (AutoFill) previous data set. If I accept the suggestion, the browser fills some fields and the two DDLs. The State DDL doesn't fire the SelectedIndexChanged event. This event will be fired when I click at Save Button. It seems that the site holds the SelectedIndexChanged event and execute it before the form save method. But on this moment, City DDL SelectedValue is empty, even if on screen is showing some city that AutoFill filled.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager" runnat="server" />
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdPanel" runnat="server" >
   <asp:Triggers>
      <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="stateDDL" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
   </asp:Triggers>
   <asp:ContentTemplate>
      <asp:TextBox ID="nameTxtBox" runnat="server" />

      ... // other fields

      <asp:DropDownList ID="stateDDL" runnat="server" AutoPostBack="true" 
         OnSelectedIndexChanged="stateDDL_SelectedIndexChanged" />
      <asp:DropDownList ID="cityDDL" runnat="server" />
   </asp:ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

```
Public Sub stateDDL_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
   If IsNumeric(stateDDL.SelecteValue) Then
      FilterCities(stateDDL.SelectedValue) // Fills cityDDL according to state value
   End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can have autocomplete turned off for the entire page. Use the following in your parent page Page_Load event. Default name in WebForms is "form1". Just change form1 to whatever your page is using for the ID for  ID tag.

C# form1.Attributes.Add("autocomplete", "off");

VB.NET form1.Attributes.Add("autocomplete", "off")